# How to find second point by adding distance in first point?

Tags: math, 2d, discrete-mathematics

In the 2D. I have calculated distance 7.071068 from the coordinate:

1. (10, 10)
2. (15, 15)

But now question is that i want to find Second point by Adding distance in First Point. How to Do this?

Comment: There are an infinite number of points that are 7.07 units from (10,10). You can't choose just one based on distance.

Comment: @Kevin, what another base is required?

Comment: Do you know the direction? If you don't, then the solution is a whole circle. Even if you know the solution to be integer there will be at least 4 points that match.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, i don't know direction. How to find proper direction?

Comment: @Gani Proper direction depends on your real problem

Comment: @Gani I have provided an answer with an outline on how to find all the possible solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not enough to have the distance between 2 points to find one point given the other. You have a full circle that attend to this demand (distance).

You also need the angle between the two points (let's call it phi)

If we call distance d, to find P2 from P1:

```
X2 = X1 + d*cos(phi)

Y2 = Y1 + d*sin(phi)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are looking for integer solutions to:

dx*dx + dy*dy = 7.071068*7.071068

d2 = 7.071068*7.071068 = 50

The integer roots are 7 and 1 (49 + 1 = 50).

The easiest way to find the integer roots is by brute force. Note that d2 must be integer and that some values for d2 have more than one solution. d2=25 has the solutions (5 and 0) and (3 and 4).
Other values for d2 have no integer solutions, e.g. d2=3.

Some pseudo-code for the brute force solver:

```
d2=50;
for (i=1; i*i < d2; i++) {
  if (is_square(d2 - i*i)) {
    // integer solution found, but there may be more than one solution, so keep checking
  }
}
```